# PHP for loop iteration for $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, forms, email, session

I have an email  script that is broken up into 3 sections, sending out three separate emails at the end. One of the emails has a user specified number of fields, and the for loop, taking the number of fields, loops the table content appropriately.. Essentially, I need to iterate what's inside the for loop like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['ct']; $i++) {

$_SESSION['sec4_fieldname_' .$i] = $_REQUEST['sec4_fieldname_' . $i];
$_SESSION['sec4_othername_' .$i] = $_REQUEST['sec4_othername_' . $i];
$_SESSION['sec4_finalname_' .$i] = $_REQUEST['sec4_finalname_' . $i];
}
```

Is there a way to iterate into the session's name correctly? 
Where fieldname is the name of one of the fields to be looped, along with the ones underneath. And $_SESSION['ct'] is the count of the number of times this needs to be looped based on users decisions

I -know- this isn't the correct syntax for doing this.. Is anyone able to help me understand how to do this? And if not like this, what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should probablu use arrays, so the input names would be `name="sec4_fieldname[]"`.  Much easier.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the context of this. Can you give an example and explanation?

Comment: Can you provide example output of $_REQUEST or submitted FORM data?

Comment: the form data is just a simple table with headers and the data from the for loop fills in a new line underneath for each user field created. As there are three pages to the form, i've consolidated it for the client into one script based on what page they are on. As such, i'm having to use session variables to store the previous pages information so that it can all be input into the email correctly and sent out. Everything in the email works fine bar this for loop. Each new field gets  +1 on it. So initially there's only sec4_fieldname_1. But it increases with every user addition.

Comment: I don't understand this either. What do you mean by *itterate into the session's name correctly*?

Comment: the number of loops is determined by CT. For every loop i want the "sec4_fieldname_" part to be picked up as "sec4_fieldname_" . $i. where i is the loop number. I want the session variable to be stored as "sec4_fieldname_1" on the first loop for example.

Comment: does your number of loops HAVE to be set by CT? What about just by using the number of values passed to the PHP script?

Comment: I think you should really be using multidimensional array as @Martin is demonstrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input name="sec4[fieldname][]" value="fieldl">
<input name="sec4[othername][]" value="otherr">
<input name="sec4[finalname][]" value="finan">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is sent via POST/GET/REQUEST to the PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_REQUEST['sec4'] as $outerRowKey => $outerRowVal){
    // In this foreach loads all the values 
    // listed above in the HTML.
    // please note the IF clause is simply to only deal with the
    // array values and leaves the string values untouched. 
    if(is_array($outerRowVal)){
        foreach ($outerRowVal as $innerRowKey => $innerRowVal){
            //In this foreach loads the 'fieldname' or
            // 'othername' or 'finalname' arrays in turn
            // and saves its data to the session. 
            $_SESSION['sec4'][$outerRowKey][] = $innerRowVal;
            }
     unset($innerRowKey,$innerRowVal);
    }
 }
 unset($outerRowKey, $outerRowVal);
```

This will present you with a $_SESSION structure of:

```
$_SESSION['sec4']['fieldname'][0] = "fieldl"
$_SESSION['sec4']['fieldname'][1]
$_SESSION['sec4']['fieldname'][2]
$_SESSION['sec4']['fieldname'][...]

$_SESSION['sec4']['othername'][0] = "other"
$_SESSION['sec4']['othername'][1]
$_SESSION['sec4']['othername'][2]
$_SESSION['sec4']['othername'][...]

$_SESSION['sec4']['finalname'][0] = "finan"
$_SESSION['sec4']['finalname'][1]
$_SESSION['sec4']['finalname'][2]
$_SESSION['sec4']['finalname'][...]
```

You can of course adapt the structure yourself but the key point is that using the `[]` syntax on the end of the name part of the input sets it as an array value and it is appended when sent to the `$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` array for using by the PHP script. Using Foreach you then do not need to care how many there are, because they are all treated equally.

This is a much neater and tidier and more adaptable solution than manually editing the key values in a numerical loop. This also means that if you add or remove values from the form input then the PHP code still works perfectly.

To take your above code and *without* changing the method and simply to improve the execution of the code (as well as make it more readable), try this:

**NOTE:** *this is inferior to using arrays. This sort of issue is what arrays are perfect at handling.*

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['ct']; $i++) {
    $a = 'sec4_fieldname_' .$i;
    $b = 'sec4_othername_' .$i;
    $c = 'sec4_finalname_' .$i;
    $_SESSION[$a] = $_REQUEST[$a];  
    $_SESSION[$b] = $_REQUEST[$b];
    $_SESSION[$c] = $_REQUEST[$c];
    }
unset($a,$b,$c,$i);
```

Comment: I have a nagging feeling my foreach loops are missing something :-/